# What will happen after the maximum number of images pushed to ECR repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, docker-container

According to [Amazon ECR Service Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/service_limits.html), the maximum number of images per repository is 1,000. After exceeding this limit, the oldest image won't remove automatically. It blocks pushing to the repository. So I have to clean old images manually.

**Update:** AWS introduced [ECR Lifecycle Policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/clean-up-your-container-images-with-amazon-ecr-lifecycle-policies/). We can now automate the cleanup with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having experienced this exact scenario, I can confirm that upon reaching the limit, AWS will block you from pushing with this very unhelpful error message:

`Error pushing to registry: Server error: 403 trying to push <repo>:<label> manifest`

You'll need to manage the number of repositories yourself.  As there is currently no built in garbage collection (nor 'remove oldest') functionality, you have a few options:

1. Remove the images via the console (which really is just woeful with so many images)
2. Write your own tool that interfaces with the AWS CLI/SDK using the `ecr batch-delete-image` commands
3. Request a limit to the maximum number you can store per repository.  We've recently done this and was very easy to get the 1,000 limit increased to 5,000.

Comment: This answer is outdated, you can now use ECR lifecycle policies (see other answers or updated question).

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to define ECR lifecycle policies.  Here is a how-to guide:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/clean-up-your-container-images-with-amazon-ecr-lifecycle-policies/

Answer (score 0):

As of April-2021, I see the limit to be 10k for both # of repo and images-per-repo

[image]