# AWS ECS 1000 images per repository limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

The official doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/service_limits.html) says :

> Amazon ECR limits the number of images to 1,000 per repository.

But I'd like to know what happens if this limit is reached :

Does it crashes if I'd like to push the 1001 image ?

Does it eject the first image ?

Does it eject the first non-tagged image ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What will happen after the maximum number of images pushed to ECR repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755658/what-will-happen-after-the-maximum-number-of-images-pushed-to-ecr-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push fails, simple as that